# Powershell Get Record Txt DNS (Windows 7)

Tags: powershell, dns, record, txt

I need to get an authentication key included in a dns txt record

Here is my command in Windows 10 but it does not work in Windows 7 (Powershell 2.0)

```
$query = Resolve-DnsName -Type txt -name Key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Error = Resolve-DnsName command not found

I need Resolve-DnsName equivalent for Powershell 2.0 and get dns txt record

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What does `it does not work` mean? Wrong output? No output? Error message? [Edit] the question and include the information there. Do not add a comment, those are hard to read, and the question body should be self-sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

DnsClient Module coming with Windows 8.0 and Windows Server 2012. It cannot be used on Windows 7
you can use nslookup :

```
nslookup -query=txt yourname
```